# Determine min/max values for three numbers

Tags: if-statement, vbscript, scripting, qtp

I have been trying to execute a VBScript using an `If ... Then` condition.
This is what I have to display.

I have to show 3 messages: one for highest number, second is for lowest number, and third will show a message `"The numbers are the same"` (if they are all equal). 
I need to get the three pop ups to appear one by one.

I have tried this:

```
Option explicit

Dim Gn, Sn, En

Gn= inputbox("enter first number")
Sn= inputbox("enter second number")
En =inputbox("enter third number")

If ((Gn > Sn) AND (Gn > En)) then
Msgbox ("The Highest Number Is =" & Gn)
End if
If ((En =Gn) AND (En =Sn)) then
Msgbox ("The Numbers Are Equal =" & En)
End if
If ((Sn<Gn) AND (Sn <En))then
Msgbox ("The Lowest Number Is =" & Sn)
End If
```

This code executes successfully if the value of the first variable satisfies all the conditions, but there's still a problem. It does not show the three messages one by one. For example, if `Gn` > `En` and `Sn`, then it runs successfully.

There's an alternative way, but it's too much lengthy and complex.

```
Option explicit

Dim Gn, Sn, En

Gn= inputbox("enter first number")
Sn= inputbox("enter second number")
En =inputbox("enter third number")

If ((Gn > Sn) AND(Sn > En ) AND (Gn > En)) then
Msgbox ("The Highest number is = " & Gn & "The lowest number is = " & Sn & "The numbers are not equal" )
end if
```

I will have to try all permutations and combinations to get the above one to work.

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

If you want the message boxes to *always* appear, don't put them within `If` statements. Determine your min/max values first and then just display your message boxes unconditionally.

This would be easier if you created a couple functions (`Min` and `Max`) to help you out:

```
Function Min(x, y)
    If x < y Then Min = x Else Min = y
End Function

Function Max(x, y)
    If x > y Then Max = x Else Max = y
End Function
```

Then you could easily determine the minimum and maximum numbers, and also if all three numbers are equal:

```
intMin = Min(Min(Gn, Sn), En)
intMax = Max(Max(Gn, Sn), En)
fEqual = (intMin = intMax)

MsgBox "Highest number is " & intMax
MsgBox "Lowest number is "  & intMin
If fEqual Then MsgBox "All three numbers are equal"
```

Finally, you'll want to make sure your input is being treated as numeric instead of as strings. `InputBox()` will return a string, so you'll need to convert that value to a numeric or else your comparisons won't come out right.

If you want to assume numbers are being entered, just cast the return value:

```
' Assume integers are being entered. If floating point, use CDbl() instead.
Gn = CLng(inputbox("enter first number"))
```

Otherwise, you can test the return value to see if it's numeric and then cast it properly:

```
Gn = inputbox("enter first number")

If Not IsNumeric(Gn) Then
    MsgBox Gn & " is not numeric."
Else
    Gn = CLng(Gn)
End If
```